# WiringPi on windows

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I just got Visual Studios Community 2015 for my laptop and I am beginning in C++. Is it possible to install "wiringpi.h" on a computer running windows. I was wondering because when I compile my program It comes out with this error: "can't open source file "wiringPi.h" ".